# How to call modal dialog from inside Flask function

Tags: python, html, flask

With the Bootstrap modal dialog's `id="myModal"`:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
...
</div>
```

I can call it by clicking a simple `<a>`. It happens because `<a>`s `data-target` attribute is linked to the modal dialog's `id` `myModal` :

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Click Here</a>
```

I wonder if there is a way to call this modal dialog by its `id` from inside of Flask python function.

```
@app.route('/call_modal', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def call_modal():
    # ... call modal dialog by its id?
```

Comment: Flask doesn't have access to browser. It only sends HTML/JavaScript as response on browser request. JavaScript/AJAX can send request to browser/Flask and receive response and then shows modal - but JavaScript have to send message first to Flask. Flask can't send message to JavaScript first. Flask may only generate response with HTML page and JavaScript which will display Dialog.

Comment: Try my solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use another modal plugin to make it work, such as [Remodal](https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal). Similarly as Bootstrap modal, every modal has an id, you can call it as an anchor, like this: `//example.com#myModal`.

In your view.py:

```
@app.route('/call_modal', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def call_modal():
    redirect(url_for('index') + '#myModal')
```