# Bad Request/form not defined on modal form submit to email - flask

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, flask, python-3.5

I am trying to submit a modal form with various input data to my email through my flask app, but am getting 400 bad request error or    "form is not defined" error because I tried using this line in the function:

```
form = modal1form(request.form)
```

Not sure whats wrong here - note: modal is located at /dashboard/projects/#modal1
 Thanks

```
# new project function
@app.route('/dashboard/projects/#modal1form/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def new_project():
    try:

        if request.method == "POST":
            if form.validate() == False:
                flash('Invalid!  All fields are required.')
                return redirect(url_for('new_project'))

            else:
                msg = Message(request.form['name'], sender='request.form["email"]', recipients=['myemail@gmail.com'])
                msg.body = """
                From: %s %s \n
                %s \n \n %s \n \n %s \n %s \n
                %s
                """ % (request.form['wtype', 'wpack', 'bts', 'fts', 'comments'])
                mail.send(msg)

                flash('Congratulations! A new project has been submitted.')
                gc.collect()
                return render_template('dashboardProjects.html')

        elif request.method == 'GET':
            return render_template("dashboardProjects.html")

    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

## modal form

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal fade">

  <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('new_project') }}" role="form" id="modal1form" name="modal1form">
      <div class="form-group text-center">
         <label for="name" class="control-label text-center"> Name </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group text-center">
        <label for="email" class="text-center"> Email Address </label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email">
       </div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">           
              <div class="form-group"> <br>
                <label for="wtype"> Website Type </label> <br>
        <h5 class="form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="wtype" id="wtype1" value="Static"> Static
        </h5>
        <h5 class="form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="wtype" id="wtype2" value="Blog"> Blog
        </h5> 
                </div>
</div>            
        <br>     

<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="wpack"> Website Package </label> <br>
        <h5 class="form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" name="wpack" type="radio" id="wpack2" value="Blog"> Basic
        </h5>
        <h5 class="form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" name="wpack" type="radio" id="wpack3" value="Ecommerce"> Standard <br>
        </h5>    
                    </div>
</div>  

            <li class="dropdown pull-right list-unstyled" aria-expanded="false" style="position: top;"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" style="font-size: 14px;">  <span class="caret"></span>  <label for="template"> <i class="fa fa-cube"></i> Template </label> </a> 
             <ul class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled">
      <li><h5 class="text-center"> <i class="fa fa-cubes"></i> Templates</h5></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="Basic Template1" tabIndex="-1"><input name="bts" type="radio"/>&nbsp;Basic Template 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="Basic Template2" tabIndex="-1"><input name="bts" type="radio"/>&nbsp;Basic Template 2</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="Footer 1" tabIndex="-1"><input name="fts" type="radio"/>&nbsp; Footer 1</a></li>

              </ul>
              </li>
 </div>

    <div class="form-group text-center"> <br>
        <label for="comments"> Other Details </label>
        <textarea name="comments" class="form-control" id="comments" placeholder="Additional comments, ideas, requests, questions?"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block"> </p>
     </div>
  </form>

  </div>     
      <div class="modal-footer brick">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" form="modal1form">Submit</button>
      </div>
```

Comment: I don't see a definition of your Form in Flask. You need to create a Form class in order to use form.validate. Have a look at Flask-WTForms http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/wtforms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERROR 1: form is not defined

If you want to use Flask-WTF, you must create a Form, like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DateRrequired

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'a very secret string'

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringForm('Your Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField()

app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        ...
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

Then you need to render the form in HTML template:

```
<form method="post">
{{ form.name() }}
{{ form.submit() }}
</form>
```

> ERROR 2: 400 Bad request

In Flask, if you get form data by `request.form['name']`, you must be ensure this input have value, that's why you get the 400 error. Instead, I recommend you to use `request.form.get('name', default_value)`, you can set a default value (as second argument) to avoid 400 error.

More details:
[flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/wtforms](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/wtforms/)

Hope it will help you.

> Maybe ERROR 3: Bootstrap Modal

You can't open a modal with anchor name, like `example.com#MyModal`, but other  modal plugin can. Check my answer on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40569103/how-to-call-modal-dialog-from-inside-flask-function/40569830#40569830) about this.

Comment: Ok, I can create a formclass with Flask-WTF.  My issue is my modal form(above is abbreviated) has name, email, 5 boolean checkbox group, 3 radio list groups of 5, 12, and 2 fields, and comments text area field.  Would I need a class with 25 lines explicitly defining all those fields?  And I wanted to keep my custom styled bootstrap form, I notice with flaskWTF I have to rebuild an entire styled form because otherwise its ugly looking, defeating the purpose of designing a custom modal..

Comment: Choice1: Stop using Flask-WTF, so you can delete `form = modal1form(request.form)`, `form.validate()`, etc. Choice2: Install Flask-Bootstrap, then you can use it's `render_form` or `qucik_form` functions to render a Bootstrap style form.

Comment: ok, i decided to scrap the modal and just build the form on a new page inside a panel, basically like the modal.  I think Im pretty close, but when i hit submit nothing happens.    heres the function and html.  this is based on a contact page i made which sends the input to my email   https://dpaste.de/xgvy   if you can point out whats wrong would be great thx. .

Comment: Your submit button is out of the form, like this `<form>...</form><button type='submit' ... >`. Besides, if I solved you problem, you may need to upvote and accept my answer. If you have more question, you can write a new one.

Comment: duh my bad.  Thanks a lot, your answer overall fixed the Issue, now I'm just working through a few errors in my form class and function.  Had to refer to flask WTF docs.